# Touch ID for login iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, touch-id

I'm making an iOS application (Obj-c) with a login form. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to use **Touch ID** to login. This will be an amazing feature for my app, but I can't find a way to do it. 
In the last PayPal update they include the **Touch ID** login - so there is a way to do it.

**EDIT:**  I know how to get if the user enter the correct Touch ID, but I don't know what to do after that. 
What if the user enter his username and then add the Touch ID correctly? How could I know this user have this Touch ID?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-integrating-touch-id--cms-21949

Comment: Try this : http://www.sitepoint.com/integrating-touch-id-ios-app/

Comment: That isn't what I'm looking for. This is clearly - I can use the touch id to find is this the device owner, but I want to use the user Touch ID for LOGIN.

Comment: check first if the touch id is configured and your device supports touch id. then call the CanEvaluate policy and in success and failure delegate, do whatever you want

Comment: Hey @StefanTabakov If my answer helped, it would be great if you could consider marking it correct! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Okay first create an action like so:

We need more detail tough, as I do not know if you mean Obj-C or swift, I'll just post both.

**Obj-C**

Firstly import the local authentication framework

`#import <LocalAuthentication/LocalAuthentication.h>`

Then we create an IBAction and add the following code:

```
- (IBAction)authenticateButtonTapped:(id)sender {
   LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];

   NSError *error = nil;
   if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) {
       [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
               localizedReason:@"Are you the device owner?"
                         reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

           if (error) {
               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                               message:@"There was a problem verifying your identity."
                                                              delegate:nil
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
               [alert show];
               return;
           }

           if (success) {
               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                                               message:@"You are the device owner!"
                                                              delegate:nil
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
               [alert show];

           } else {
               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                               message:@"You are not the device owner."
                                                              delegate:nil
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
               [alert show];
           }

       }];

   } else {

       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                       message:@"Your device cannot authenticate using TouchID."
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];

   }
}
```

The just connect your IBAction to a button that will prompt authentication.

However in **Swift** you would use:

Add the following framework to your project: **LocalAuthentication**
Then import it in your swift file:

```
import LocalAuthentication
```

Then create the following method that will prompt you to use touch id:

```
func authenticateUser() {
        // Get the local authentication context.
        let context = LAContext()

        // Declare a NSError variable.
        var error: NSError?

        // Set the reason string that will appear on the authentication alert.
        var reasonString = "Authentication is needed to access your notes."

        // Check if the device can evaluate the policy.
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
            [context .evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reasonString, reply: { (success: Bool, evalPolicyError: NSError?) -> Void in

                if success {

                }
                else{
                    // If authentication failed then show a message to the console with a short description.
                    // In case that the error is a user fallback, then show the password alert view.
                    println(evalPolicyError?.localizedDescription)

                    switch evalPolicyError!.code {

                    case LAError.SystemCancel.rawValue():
                        println("Authentication was cancelled by the system")

                    case LAError.UserCancel.rawValue():
                        println("Authentication was cancelled by the user")

                    case LAError.UserFallback.rawValue():
                        println("User selected to enter custom password")
                        self.showPasswordAlert()

                    default:
                        println("Authentication failed")
                        self.showPasswordAlert()
                    }
                }

            })]
        }
        else{
            // If the security policy cannot be evaluated then show a short message depending on the error.
            switch error!.code{

            case LAError.TouchIDNotEnrolled.rawValue():
                println("TouchID is not enrolled")

            case LAError.PasscodeNotSet.rawValue():
                println("A passcode has not been set")

            default:
                // The LAError.TouchIDNotAvailable case.
                println("TouchID not available")
            }

            // Optionally the error description can be displayed on the console.
            println(error?.localizedDescription)

            // Show the custom alert view to allow users to enter the password.
            self.showPasswordAlert()
        }
    }
```

Lastly from the **func viewDidLoad** call the function like so: `authenticateUser()`

Hope that helps. Keep coding.

Sources: 
Swift:
[App Coda iOS 8 Touch ID Api](http://www.appcoda.com/touch-id-api-ios8/)

Objective-C:
[tutPlus iOS Touch ID](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-integrating-touch-id--cms-21949)

Thanks to Matt Logan for the updated swift code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to use the fingerprint for login. What I have to do if the fingerprint is correct? just let the user with that username to enter?

Comment: just log him in in the if success method in swift. Enter his username and password pragmatically for instance or present the desired view controller.

Comment: This isn't right. If someone else add my username and enter his Touch ID at his device? I have to let him in?

Comment: Look, touch id will only let the Master user of his own device in. No one else, as only the owners fingerprint is stored on the device.

Comment: Yes, I said at another device. I'll try to explain again.. 

You know my username. And enter it at your device. And you use your fingerprint. This will let you in my account.

Comment: no, unless you also know the password and configure it to work with your touch id

Comment: touch id is not associated with username, its associated with your device  and configured touch ids. configured touch ids can  pass your login check

Comment: This code is not your own. You should provide a link to where you got it so you give the original author credit. It's proper etiquette. If you are going to post it as your own, though, at a minimum you should bring it up to date with the latest Swift version. The method .toRaw() is no longer available and has been replaced with .rawValue, for example.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I generally always quote the original source. I have by mistake forgotten it here. Thank. I'll update it as soon as possible :-)

Comment: The biggest problem is it will compare finger print to device owner and not yours...

Comment: Yeah. But touch ID can **only** compare to the device owner.

Comment: Thanks for the code. perfectly working but why it delaying to show response of validation ? Why not show immediate response like iPhone Phone lock ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what I have to do!
After the first user Login I'll save his password (at NSUserdefaults for example).

If the user want to use his Touch ID at the next login - I'll ask him for the Touch ID and if it's correct i'll let him in with the password saved at the beginning.

Thanks to  Julian :)

Comment: think about first time login . Your are on the wrong track

Comment: Your welcome. If you're happy please accept my answer as correct so that other people can see it if they face the same problem. Glad i could help :-)

Comment: One more thing , if your app contains some user specific data then it will create problems for differentiating user specific data with only touch id based login

Comment: Muhammad Adnan, why this is wrong track? At the first login the user can't use his fingerprint. But after that I can log it with the password he already add.

Comment: You should check if you can evaluate touch id or not (first time and any time )

Comment: Yes, definitely. If the user device haven't Touch ID, he'll see just the username and password fields. :)

Comment: Hey. If my answer worked, please select it as correct in order  for others to see. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer is correct for "how to use the touch id at all".
 I found the answer of my question in the discussion bellow your answer.

Comment: @StefanTabakov After logging in for second time how will you verify that the fingerprint authenticated is that of the "user" whose details is saved in NSUserDefaults ? Is there any parameter from the LA api that allows to tag a user with his biometric login ?

Comment: @JulianEngel13 After logging in for second time how will you verify that the fingerprint authenticated is that of the "user" whose details is saved in NSUserDefaults ? Is there any parameter from the LA api that allows to tag a user with his biometric login ?